# Send event from flutter app using Laravel Echo

Tags: flutter, serversocket, pusher, laravel-echo

I'm working on a taxi-hailing app and we are using flutter. The driver must send location every 3 seconds and the driver location must be displayed in passenger the app. Is it possible to send data from the app to Pusher using laravel echo?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [client events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#client-events) to achieve this.

> To broadcast client events, you may use Echo's whisper method:
>
> ```
> Echo.private(`chat.${roomId}`)
>     .whisper('typing', {
>         name: this.user.name
>     });
> ```
>
> To listen for client events, you may use the listenForWhisper method:
>
> ```
> Echo.private(`chat.${roomId}`)
>     .listenForWhisper('typing', (e) => {
>         console.log(e.name);
>     });
> ```

Comment: Is this library available also for Flutter?